# If $\varphi_{i}^{j}:V\to \mathbb{R}$ smooth, then $(\varphi_{i}^{j}(p))_{1\leq i,j\leq k}$ is smooth.

Tags: differential-geometry

Could you help me with the following question, please?

Let $M$ a smooth manifold and $V\subseteq M$ a open set. The maps $\varphi_{i}^{j}:V\to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth for all $i, j\in\{1,...,k\}$. Is the map $F:V\to M(k\times k,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $p\mapsto (\varphi_{i}^{j}(p))_{1\leq i,j\leq k}$ smooth?

Here
\begin{equation}(\varphi_{i}^{j}(p))_{1\leq i,j\leq k}=\begin{pmatrix}\varphi_{1}^{1}(p) & \varphi_{2}^{1}(p) & \cdots & \varphi_{k}^{1}(p)\\ \varphi_{1}^{2}(p) & \varphi_{2}^{2}(p) & \cdots & \varphi_{k}^{2}(p)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \varphi_{1}^{k}(p) & \varphi_{2}^{k}(p) & \cdots & \varphi_{k}^{k}(p) \end{pmatrix}.\end{equation}

I know that $p \mapsto(\varphi_{1}^{i}(p), \varphi_{2}^{i}(p),  \cdots, \varphi_{k}^{i}(p))$ is a smooth map, and I tried to relate this idea to the matrix but to no avail, and I don't know if this idea is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $M(k\times k, \mathbb{R})$ is a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$. More precisely, there is a smooth atlas consisting of a single chart $(M(k\times k, \mathbb{R}), \Psi)$ where $\Psi : M(k\times k, \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{k^2}$ maps a matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ to the vector $(a_{11}, \dots, a_{1k}, a_{21}, \dots, a_{2k}, \dots, a_{k1}, \dots, a_{kk})$.

The map $F : V \to M(k\times k, \mathbb{R})$ is smooth if and only if $\Psi\circ F : V \to \mathbb{R}^{k^2}$ is smooth, and a map to Euclidean space is smooth if and only if each of its component functions are smooth. The result now follows as the component functions of $\Psi\circ F$ are $\varphi_i^j$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a book where I can review these kinds of results?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by 'these kinds of results'. I like Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.